# heroku nodejs app - events.js:167 Error Unhandled 'error' event : spawn java ENOENT

Tags: java, node.js, heroku, pdfbox, spawn

I'm having a node-js app on Heroku using the pdfMerge.js library.

following the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdfmerger) I'm using the stream event mechanism  as a callback to identify the end of the process

then an exception is thrown :
events.js:167 Error: spawn java ENOENT.

I'm almost sure it's happening because I'm messing required java installation as described here:

> pdfmerger combines multiple PDF-files into a single PDF-file. It is a node module that utilizes the Apache PDFBox Library, which the required functionality are distributed along with this module. The only requirement for this module to run, is having Java 6 or higher in the path.

I'm Not familiar enough with Heroku installation/configuration process in order to make it work.

thanks in advance

Comment: https://github.com/Vincit/heroku-buildpack-java-nodejs   for heroku buildpack combine  node && java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add Java to your app by adding the `heroku/jvm` buildpack like this:

```
$ heroku buildpacks:add -i 1 heroku/jvm
```

Then redeploy with `git commit --allow-empty` and `git push heroku master`.